# FastAPI skip id when insert record encounter an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Am trying to setup failure handler when modifying database, but i realize every time it face an exception, it will skip the record when the next request is success.

I've tried to rollback the database when encounter an exception, it did not insert the record as expected but it still skip the id. Is there any way to not skip the id when encounter error?

```
def insertUser(db: Session, user: userCreate):
try:
    dbUser = userModel(
        email       = user.email,
        password    = hashPassword(user.password),
        first_name  = user.firstName,
        last_name   = user.lastName,
        phone       = user.phone,
        about       = user.about,
        country     = user.country
    )
    db.add(dbUser)
    db.flush()
    db.refresh(dbUser)


    return userSerialize(dbUser, None)

except Exception as e:
    db.rollback()
    raise HTTPException(status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.args)

finally:
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

[image]

Comment: In general it's expected that auto-incrementing ids are not rolled back in the event of an error - it's very difficult to get the right behaviour in situations where more than one process is inserting records.  It's best not to rely on ids being anything other than "labels" for rows in the database; the fact that they appear to form a sequence is coincidental.

Comment: @snakecharmerb that does make sense. I thought `flush()` just imitating the db so whenever we encounter a problem we still can revoke the changes like never happened, then when we call `commit()` it really submit it to the real db.

Comment: Auto-incrementing ids are generally allocated at flush time.